# Mysql injection

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are mysql_real_escape_string() and mysql_escape_string() sufficient for app security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secur)

So how do you protect against it now magic qoutes is deprecated.

is

```
mysql_real_escape_string();
```

enough?

Answer (score 1):

good place to start http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 0):

It appears thats all you would need:

> This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.