# Why doesn't mysql_real_escape_string() work correctly?

Tags: php, character-encoding, mysql-real-escape-string

in documentation of [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) it say:

> ...,taking into account the current
>   character set of the connection so
>   that it is safe to place it in a
>   mysql_query()

now why didn't it work correctly in [this example](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html)?

```
$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("database", $c);
// change our character set
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'gbk'", $c);
// create demo table
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
    password VARCHAR(32)
) CHARACTER SET 'GBK'", $c);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('foo','bar'), ('baz','test')", $c);
// now the exploit code
$_POST['username'] = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27) . ' OR username = username /*'; 
$_POST['password'] = 'anything'; 
// Proper escaping, we should be safe, right?
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'], $c);
$passwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'], $c);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE  username = '{$user}' AND password = '{$passwd}'";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $c);
echo mysql_num_rows($res); // will print 2, indicating that we were able to fetch all records
```

we changed character-set by `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'gbk'", $c)` before calling `mysql_real_escape_string`, so why didn't this function know new character-set?

Comment: I'd suggest adding your example to the question instead of just linking to it, it will make it easier for people willing to help to find you an answer

Comment: I use `SET NAMES encoding` to set the character set and never had any problems. In all cases you may use PDO (if you are using php > 5.1) which is recommended by PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET CHARACTER SET` / `SET NAMES` is **not enough** to protect against the GBK exploit, depending on what version of MySQL you are using.

If you can, use [`mysql_set_charset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) / [`mysqli_set_charset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) or real prepared statements.

You'll also want to use MySQl 5.0.77 or better.  [See this earlier post of mine for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secur/5415037#5415037).  If you are using older versions of MySQL, you *can* be vulnerable without the `_set_charset` functions.

Using prepared statements bypasses this problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the wrong documentation.

You are talking about [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) , but you are referring to documentation of [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Note the additional *i*.

The documentation for mysqli_real_escape_string says:

> mysqli::real_escape_string --
>   mysqli_real_escape_string — Escapes
>   special characters in a string for use
>   in an SQL statement, taking into
>   account the current charset of the
>   connection

Whereas, the documentation for mysql_real_escape_string (which is used in the example):

> mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes
>   special characters in a string for use
>   in an SQL statement