# how to insert multiple rows to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying for ages but can not get this working.

So far this is working perfect

```
<?
                if ($_POST['newhour_start']!=""&&$_POST['newhour_end']!="") 
                {
                    $inserthour = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hour 
                    (hour_start,hour_end,hour_day) VALUES 
                    ('".$_POST['newhour_start']."','".$_POST['newhour_end']."','".$_POST['newhour_day']."')");
                }

?>
    <td colspan="5">
        Start:<input name="newhour_start" type="text" id="newhour_start" > 
        End: <input name="newhour_end" type="text" id="newhour_end" >
        <input name="newhour_day" type="hidden" id="newhour_day" value="Monday" >
    </td>
```

My question is how can i add another 5 sets of start and end inputs to this code?

I know i can just add another input names, if statements and change their names but i want to learn the proper way.

Comment: You might want to learn about [Little Bobby Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)...

Comment: yep. re Denis's comment - See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980766/why-is-this-sql-code-insecure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an array.

So how to use an array? In HTML, you need this:

```
Start #1:<input name="newhour_start[]" type="text" /> 
End #1: <input name="newhour_end[]" type="text"  />

Start #2:<input name="newhour_start[]" type="text" /> 
End #2: <input name="newhour_end[]" type="text"  />

Start #3:<input name="newhour_start[]" type="text" /> 
End #3: <input name="newhour_end[]" type="text"  />
```

And in PHP you need this:

```
if(isset($_POST['newhour_start']) && isset($_POST['newhour_end']))
{
    foreach($_POST['newhour_start'] as $index => $start)
    {
        $hour_start = $start; // now this is the fun part - you CLEAN this string to avoid SQL injection
        $hour_end = $_POST['newhour_end'][$index]; // clean this one too

        $insert[] = "('$hour_start', '$hour_end')";
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO table (first_column, secon_column) VALUES ". implode(',', $insert);

}
```

I didn't use your table structure in this example, but I think it's simple enough so that you can learn and modify it.

Comment: i have got a small proplem now. even if the fields are empty it is inserting into database. what can i do that will only insert into if it is not empty

Comment: [code]    if(isset($_POST['newhour_start']) && isset($_POST['newhour_end']))
    {
 $newhour_day = "Monday";
 
        foreach($_POST['newhour_start'] as $index => $start)
        {
            $newhour_start = $start; // 
            $newhour_end = $_POST['newhour_end'][$index]; // clean this one too
$insert[] = "('$newhour_start', '$newhour_end', '$newhour_day')";
        } $query = "INSERT INTO hour (hour_start, hour_end, hour_day) VALUES ". implode(',', $insert);
  $inserthour = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 } [/code]

Comment: I have done this way. will it be ok?   for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['newhour_start']); $i++) { 
  if ($_POST['newhour_start'][$i] !="" && $_POST['newhour_end'][$i] !="" ) {
   $inserthour = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hour 
      (hour_start,hour_end,hour_day) VALUES 
   ('".$_POST['newhour_start'][$i]."','".$_POST['newhour_end'][$i]."','".$_POST['newhour_day'][$i]."')");
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

**Don't ever insert values in your Database without escaping them!**

The proper way of doing this would be:

1. Add your Fields or whatever to your
   HTML-Form.
2. Use the [MySQLi-class](http://de3.php.net/mysqli) in PHP to
   access your Database (it's Object
   Oriented).
3. Create a [PreparedStatement](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for your
   Insert
4. Loop over your given Fields and bind
   the parameters to your
   PreparedStatement
5. Execute the Statement
6. [Close the Database](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php) Connection.