# Will mysql real escape string prevent hack?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are mysql_real_escape_string() and mysql_escape_string() sufficient for app security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secur)

I am new to PHP and wanted to make sure.  If i use mysql_real_escape_string for user generated input (variables), the query won't be hacked?

Sample script:

```
// Getting Unique ID
$sql = "select `Person_id` from `accounts` where `username` = '$username'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pid = $row['Person_ID'];
}
mysql_free_result($query);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$newname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Full_name']);
$newgender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Patient_gender']);
$newmonth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Month']);
$newday = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Day']);
$newyear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Year']);
$newacctss = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Acct_SS']);
$newaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address']);
$newaddress2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Address2']);
$newcity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['City']);
$newstate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['State']);
$newzipcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Zip_code']);
$newhomephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Home_phone']);
$newcellphone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Cell_phone']);
$neworkphone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Work_phone']);
$newsure = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Sure']);
$newfav = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Favorite']);
$newcars = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Cars']);
$newdrinks = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Drinks']);
$newmoi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['About_moi']);

//Update Name Only
$sql = "UPDATE accounts SET `full_name` = '$newname' WHERE Username = '$username'"; 
$query1 = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

//Everything else being udpated here 
$sql2 = "UPDATE profile SET `Patient_gender` = '$newgender', 
`Month` = '$newmonth', `Day` = '$newday', `Year` = '$newyear', 
`Acct_SS` = '$newacctssn', `Address` = '$newaddress', 
`Address2` = '$newaddress2', `City` = '$newcity', `State` = '$newstate', 
`Zip_code` = '$newzipcode', `Home_phone` = '$newhomephone', 
`Cell_phone` = '$cellphone', `Work_phone` = '$neworkphone', 
`Sure` = '$newsure', `Favorite` = '$newfav', `Cars` = '$newcars', 
`Drinks` = '$newdrinks', `About_moi` = '$newmoi' WHERE Person_id = '$pid'"; 
$query2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

Comment: It depends. As long as it's string data surrounded by quotes, yes. Can you show your real life query?

Comment: inb4 "Use prepared statements" comment in 3.... 2.... 1....

Comment: Stack Overflow has a search box: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_real_escape_string+hack

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use straight mysql.**  Use the `mysqli`(notice the i) or PDO library and use prepared statements. Using prepared statements is more secure than using straight queries and including the variable in the query string.

According to the PHP documentation, [mysql will be deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). It is no longer underdevelopment and the `mysqli` and `PDO` extensions should be used instead.

Comment: PDO is a great idea, however, you can achieve the same results without it.  The biggest benefit to PDO is not that it adds more security, but makes it easier to write queries securely.

Comment: care to define "a lot more secure"?

Comment: how are prepared statements more safe?

Comment: The database engine doesn't combine the bound variables into the SQL statement and then parse the whole thing; The bound variables are kept separate and never parsed as a generic SQL statement. That way, the user can't inject SQL because it's never parsed as SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty safe if your using both quotes and mysql_real_escape_string.  You may want to look at PDO or at least mysqli for other reasons.