# This query is over-escaped! Need a simple idea

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, escaping

So I've created a simple PHP function to 'UPDATE' my MySQL row just by updating the array that is received by PHP.

```
function db_updateproduct(array $new, array $old = array()) {
    $diff = array_diff($new, $old);
    return 'INSERT INTO table (`'.mysql_real_escape_string(implode(array_keys($diff), '`,`')).'`) VALUES \''.mysql_real_escape_string(implode(array_values($diff), '\',\'')).'\'';
}
```

...

**Update (with Accepted answer)**

```
function db_updateproduct(array $new, array $old = array()) {
    $diff = array_diff($new, $old);
    return 'INSERT INTO `Product` (`'.implode(array_keys($diff), '`,`').'`) VALUES (\''
        .implode(array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($diff)), '\', \'').'\')';
}
```

Now...

```
echo db_updateproduct(array('a' => 'on\'e', 'b' => 'two', 'c' => 'three'));
```

returns:

```
INSERT INTO `Product` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES ('on\'e', 'two', 'three')
```

**(As expected/wanted!)**

Comment: First shot: Use double quotes for your surounding query string " instead of single quotes '. Do it in implode as well "', '". This should avoid confusing escape sequences.

Comment: I don't get it. Then why did you put backslashes here? `implode(array_values($diff), '\',\'')` Am I missing something?

Comment: **micfra**:, Unfortunately the quotes will still get escaped.

Comment: **rgin**: The backslashed are to use a literal quote inside the quotes.
`'\',\''` will only output `','`. It's the mysql_real_escape_string that's doing the damage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [run the escape function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#102130) on the keys and values with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

<strike>$escaped_keys = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_keys($diff));</strike>

```
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($diff));
```

Then you can do your `implode()` magic on these two arrays.

---

**UPDATE:** As @YourCommonSense correctly pointed it out, it does not really make sense to run `mysql_real_escape_string()` on values that will be used in the query as field names/table names/etc. It correctly escapes `\x00`, `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `'`, `"` and `\x1a`, but it **does NOT escape the backtick**, so the query is still vulnerable to attacks.

You should validate the field names (so only the expected names can be used) or even better, use prepared queries (I recommend PDO).

Suggested reading:

- [Are mysql_real_escape_string() and mysql_escape_string() sufficient for app security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secu)

Comment: Didn't think of that, but it sounds great. Thanks mate! I'll give it a go now!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Looking at this method, you don't really know where the keys are coming from. If they come directly from a form, the keys can be manipulated (thus should be escaped, if validation did not take place - we don't know this and it is out of the question's scope). I don't feel this is worth a downvote, but I understand it is your decision only how you use them.

Comment: oh really? imagine I manipulated these keys hard. say, made `c` one looks like "c`) VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL);DROP TABLE USERS; --" What will your escaping do with it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Got it, it is trivial, you're right. I will correct my answer.

Comment: this is not that trivial. 95% of local folks do believe that escaping does some magic "sanitization", making whatever data "safe". so, your answer only follows this very common misbelief.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I did not pay enough attention, should not write answers on SO when too drunk. Thanks.

Comment: Hehe, I like the desc though :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks. There was no point. (see next line)
The Title is 'This query is over-escaped!' though :P

Comment: @bazmegakapa The keys are safe (they're coming from a safe source)

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, doing mysql_real_escape_string on the array keys is an example of absolutely useless action.

Comment: As a matter of fact, this is not an answer :).

Comment: Yes, it is useless. I'm not really sure why I tried to sanitize it.

But... this is not an answer.

Comment: i will up vote it anyway since such a good point is worth it. It would be much better though if you provided an explanation of why's that (as you did in the comment above)