# Escaping quotation marks php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I escape quotation marks via `addslashes($str)`.

When i save the input from text fields to a MySQL database, is that a sufficient protection against MySQL injections or do I need to filter the input further because you can bypass this escape method? Or is there any better way to  do this?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secu

Comment: No, it is awful. See the duplicate questions for the correct way to do it.

Comment: there are tons of posts on that, though :)

Answer (score 2):

You should read about prepared statements in PDO:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Escaping quotes is definitely not enough. The safest thing to do is to use parameter binding. See the docs for [mysqli_stmt::bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can check all parameters for any of the following things, depending on expected values:

- Is the value of the variable something meaningful?
- Is the value of the variable within a reasonable value range?
- Is the value of the variable inside a predefined maximum length?

Those are some elementary checks that can save you a lot of trouble. Also, to avoid more problems:

- Always filter file uploads, and never execute anything uploaded.
- Never, ever execute SQL or evaluate code that has a direct part of user input. Always parse your inputs first, so that you are certain it does not contain any abnormalities.

Answer (score -1):

You can do excaping like this:

```
<?php  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username =   '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");  
?>
```

Comment: Please do not recommend functions that the PHP manual puts a big red "Do not use" notice on.

Comment: also plain text passwords? wtf?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using mysql_real_escape_string or similar function (depending on what DB access methodology you are using).

Comment: Building queries by mashing together strings leaves too much room for error. Use bound parameters. That function also comes with a big red "use something else" alert in the PHP manual.

Comment: Yes, but many people do not necessarily want to use some database abstraction layer or want the additional overhead that prepared statements may bring for cases where you are only doing single data inserts (as opposed to performing the same query multiple times with different data where prepared statements really shine performance-wise).  Also some users may not have MYSQLi extension available on their server or the ability/know how to install it.