# upload image with other fileds into db

Tags: php, field, image-uploading

I want to store my values to db. Also I want to upload one image. My insert query is below. It's not working.

```
$query = mysql_query("insert into designingoption set name='$name1',positionCode='$pos',assetType='$ass',price='$price',createdOn='$createdon',lastModifiedOn='$laston',lastModifiedBy='$lastby')",$con);
```

Here name=$name is my image upload field..

Comment: yeah what error u having?

Comment: $pos=$_POST['position'];
$ass=$_POST['asset'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$createdon=$_POST['createdon'];
$laston=$_POST['laston'];
$lastby=$_POST['lastby'];

Comment: This is my fields..values are not stored in the database..thats my problem.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include more of your current code, the precise problem you ran into and where you need help - thanks.

Comment: You want `INSERT` or `UPDATE`

Comment: give us what mysql spit out to you, are yout trying to store ur image name of binary of it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats not working, but, i gotta a pretty good idea the values are not inserted since you used ' (single quote) around $variables.

Try like this.

```
 $query=mysql_query("insert into designingoption set name='".$name1."',positionCode='".$pos."',assetType='".$ass."',price='".$price."',createdOn='".$createdon."',lastModifiedOn='".$laston."',lastModifiedBy='".$lastby."')",$con);
```

Comment: he use double quote for query, should be no problem.he use single quote to signal mysql that it is a string

Comment: I see. Thx slier. It'd be great if 'manoranjani' posted lil more details! :0

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed the syntax for the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements.

Correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO designingoption ('name', 'positionCode', 'assetType', 'price', 'createdOn', 'lastModifiedOn', 'lastModifiedBy') VALUES ($pos, $ass, $price, $createdon, $laston, $lastby)
```

While you're at it, you might also want to consider switching to the mysqli-functions. The mysql-functions are deprecated.

Also be careful of SQL-injection. More information on the subject can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secu).

Answer (score 0):

Update your query structure.

```
INSERT INTO designingoption (name,positionCode,assetType,price,createdOn,lastModifiedOn,lastModifiedBy) VALUES ('$name1','$pos','$ass','$price','$createdon','$laston','$lastby')
```

Also, make sure that all variables are populated, otherwise you get a PHP notice.
It wouldn't hurt to enclose table rows with `, like this:

```
INSERT INTO `designingoption` (`name`,`positionCode`,`assetType`,`price`,`createdOn`,`lastModifiedOn`,`lastModifiedBy`) VALUES ('$name1','$pos','$ass','$price','$createdon','$laston','$lastby')
```

Some words are reserved by the system and must be used properly, otherwise you just receive error.

A little research as revealed (even to my surprise) that your syntax is correct.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Would you please edit your question with exact error you're getting?