# SQL Injection in this code?

Tags: php, sql

I have used [RIPS](http://rips-scanner.sourceforge.net/) to test my code for SQL injection threats. And this is one of them that has come up:

```
    Userinput reaches sensitive sink due to insecure usage of mysql_real_escape_string() without quotes (Blind exploitation)
370: mysql_query mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`Username`, `Password`, `Name`, `AccessLevel`, `LastLogin`) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($pass) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($fuln) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($al) . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($now) . "');"); 
364: $user = htmlentities($_POST['user'], ENT_QUOTES); 
365: $pass = htmlentities(md5($_POST['pass']), ENT_QUOTES); 
366: $fuln = htmlentities($_POST['fuln'], ENT_QUOTES); 
367: $al = htmlentities($_POST['al'], ENT_QUOTES); 
368: $now = time(); 
requires:
359: if($action == "newadmin")
360: if($memberinfo['AccessLevel'] == 3)
363: if($_GET['submit'] == "new")
369: if($user && $pass && $fuln)
```

Could someone please explain to me why this code would be vulnerable to SQL injection? I think it is either because of lack of knowledge or it is a false positive. I have been researching but I cannot find out anything new and I seem to be going in circles.

Comment: md5 for pass? in 2013?

Comment: Intead of mysql use PDO or MYSQLI with prepare statements :)

Comment: The password could do with a bit of per-database and per-use salting, too.

Comment: [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414731/are-mysql-real-escape-string-and-mysql-escape-string-sufficient-for-app-secu) has answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be a false positive. The issue described is when you use `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but you don't ensure that the result is enclosed in quotes. I checked and your strings are properly enclosed.

You should however note that the `mysql` API is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 and you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO MySQL` instead.

EDIT: Also note that as per the comments, using `md5` is not secure at all and that you should salt it by concatenating the password to a secret code before generating the hash. If you salt it, an intruder cannot simply use a pre-built dictionary of hashes to get the passwords, they would need to create a new dictonary specifically with your salt included

Comment: This absolutely obliterates my spare time over the next week, but sounds like a necessity. Thank you very much for the assistance!

Comment: Managed to completely update the website to mysqli and add salting, didn't take as long as expected!
Thanks again!